# Click after mouse over

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Dears I need some help in this code

**First:** I need to make the test case go through the if statement when

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login:popupPanel-tr")).isDisplayed());
```

`id` displayed to run the condition and if not to complete the test case without the if condition

**Second:** I need to click the element

```
driver.findElement(By.id("home:regNew")).click();
```

After the action mouse over when I do that now it doesn't click and the test case failed

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import java.sql.*;

driver.findElement(By.id("login:username")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("login:username")).sendKeys("sarasf");
driver.findElement(By.id("login:password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("login:password")).sendKeys("P@ssw0rd");
driver.findElement(By.id("login:login")).click();

if (driver.findElement(By.id("login:popupPanel-tr")).isDisplayed()) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:j_id54")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:username")).sendKeys("abasiouny_shop");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:password")).sendKeys("passw0rd");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login:login")).click();
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement subElement =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.service"));
    action.moveToElement(subElement);
    action.click();
    action.perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);   
    assertEquals("جديد",    driver.findElement(By.id("home:regNew")).getText());
}else{
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.service"));   action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector    ("p.service"))).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("home:regNew")).click();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using too many thread.sleep()? It's not a best practice and killer for your test performance. `Selenium` provides `explicit` and `implicit` waits to handles these kind of situations.

Comment: it is required to wait until the page to load

Comment: Use `Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(Something)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) what is stopping you from doing this?

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("login:popupPanel-tr")).isDisplayed())
{//condition
}
```

2) Are you saying that after mouse hover a element appears, on which you need to click? If that's the case, then you need to use Actions class mouseOver API and then perform click on element.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: 1) when I do the if condition like mentioned in the code it works fine if the browser finds this popup but when it is not displayed the test case fails I mean it doesn't go to else {}
2)That exactly what I need so I appreciate your help

Comment: ohh. Now i got it.. well you will have to do either Try/Catch or ExpectedConditions.elementTobeClickable(By). There are lots of variant in ExpectedConditions, you can choose any one which suites you with external waits (WebDriverWait). how did your second query go? where you able to go through the Actions class

Comment: No still the same problem it finds the element "p.service" and mouse over it but it can not click the element which appears below it

Comment: why can't you directly do moveToElement and then use click?

Comment: It doesn't work too. It only highlight the element but it doesn't click it

Comment: is there a public url where we can try to replicate your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Do you see ant thing wrong in the code:
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.service"));
action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.service"))).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.id("home:regNew")).click();

Comment: can't you directly reach to p.service instead of first catching some other element and then doing hover over it. Also can u do one thing use clickAndHold

Comment: I must do mouse hover over p.service so that a list appears below it then I need to click the element "home:regNew". if I didn't make hover over p.service the element "home:regNew" will not appear

Comment: can you try using clickAndHold instead of moveToElement

Comment: Glad to help you. if that is working then it might be worth if you would accept this as answer so that others too might find it handy, if they get stuck anywhere. thanks

Comment: I already did. Thank you but I hope I hope I could accept the comments too :)